# catkin cmake can't find ros packages

Tags: catkin, cmake, roscpp, ros-noetic

when building my ros1 (noetic ubuntu 20.04) package, catkin cmake can't find Catkin packages automatically.
(setting the apth for all works, but it is not the right way: `set(roscpp_DIR "/opt/ros/noetic/share/roscpp/cmake")`):

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "roscpp" with any
  of the following names:

    roscppConfig.cmake
    roscpp-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "roscpp" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "roscpp_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "roscpp"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

roscpp is installed:

```
$ apt list | grep roscpp

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

cl-roscpp-msg/focal,focal 1.14.3+ds1-11ubuntu5 all
libroscpp-core-dev/focal 0.6.13-1build1 amd64
libroscpp-dev/focal 1.14.3+ds1-11ubuntu5 amd64
libroscpp-msg-dev/focal 1.14.3+ds1-11ubuntu5 amd64
libroscpp-serialization0d/focal 0.6.13-1build1 amd64
libroscpp2d/focal 1.14.3+ds1-11ubuntu5 amd64
python3-roscpp-msg/focal,focal 1.14.3+ds1-11ubuntu5 all
ros-noetic-roscpp-core/focal,now 0.7.3-1focal.20230620.181838 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-noetic-roscpp-dbgsym/focal 1.16.0-1focal.20230620.183307 amd64
ros-noetic-roscpp-serialization-dbgsym/focal 0.7.3-1focal.20230620.181650 amd64
ros-noetic-roscpp-serialization/focal,now 0.7.3-1focal.20230620.181650 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-noetic-roscpp-traits/focal,now 0.7.3-1focal.20230620.181518 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-noetic-roscpp-tutorials-dbgsym/focal 0.10.2-1focal.20230620.184353 amd64
ros-noetic-roscpp-tutorials/focal,now 0.10.2-1focal.20230620.184353 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-noetic-roscpp/focal,now 1.16.0-1focal.20230620.183307 amd64 [installed]
ros-noetic-swri-roscpp-dbgsym/focal 2.15.2-1focal.20231105.165502 amd64
ros-noetic-swri-roscpp/focal 2.15.2-1focal.20231105.165502 amd64
ros-roscpp-msg/focal,focal 1.14.3+ds1-11ubuntu5 all
```

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.1)

project(myproject VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++17")

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Open3D REQUIRED)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  tf
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS
    include
  CATKIN_DEPENDS
    std_msgs
    sensor_msgs
    geometry_msgs
    tf
  DEPENDS
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Open3D_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

set(target_name workspace_estimator)

add_executable(${target_name}
  src/${target_name}_node.cpp
  src/${target_name}.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(${target_name}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${OpenCV_LIBS}
  ${Open3D_LIBRARIES}
)

install(
  DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION "${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}"
)

install(
  DIRECTORY config launch
  DESTINATION "${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catkin packages has to be found before other packages:

````
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
#   visualization_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  tf
)

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Open3D REQUIRED)
```
````